# Checking whether one string has more characters in it than another using Python

Tags: python, list, function, character

I'm new to Python and I have some trouble understanding how for loops work in Python. In C++ if you wanted to iterate through a list of data to find the highest value in the data, you could initiate a placeholder (depending on the data) such as `x = 0` and it would iterate through the data using `data[i]` in the loop. How do I do this in Python (example of what I want to run in Python):

```python
srt1 = "eihd39d9"
str2 = "xkn59438" 
str3 = "chdsye847"
strng = 0
srt1 = len(srt1)
str2 = len(str2)
str3 = len(str3)

def longest_word(srt1, str2, str3):
   for strng in enumerate(longest_word):
       if strng < longest_word[i]:
           strng = longest_word[i]
           print(strng)
   return
```

How do I find the longest word from the given 3 strings?

Answer (score 1):

you can use builtin method `max`

```
str1 = "eihd39d9"
str2 = "xkn59438" 
str3 = "chdsye847"
max(str1, str2, str3, key=len)
# 'chdsye847'
```

for list of strings

```
max(lst_of_strs, key=len)
```

Comment: I think you can use `max(lst_of_strs, key=len)`. No need of unpacking here.